# Generating coredump on Nvidia GPU using MPS

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

The GPU coredump could be generated by setting the environment variable "CUDA_ENABLE_COREDUMP_ON_EXCEPTION" to "1". The coredump is generated successfully when MPS is not used. But with MPS, the generated coredump file size is lesser than the size of this file without MPS. I suspect that the MPS server has exited before the coredump is generated fully. Is there any way we can get the full GPU coredump with MPS?

Cuda toolkit version : 8.0
Driver Version       : 375.26
GPU architecture     : Tesla P100 (Pascal)

Answer (score 1):

MPS + CUDA Coredump capability is not available in GPUs prior to the Volta generation.
Volta introduces some changes to MPS that make this possible.

NVIDIA will be updating the MPS docs in the future to make a note of this limitation.